# Angular filter to remove items using id

Tags: angular, typescript

How do we filter values in angular or remove values using id ? I wanted to remove data or object from the array of obejects where id is equal to 5, 12 and 9.

Apart from that , we are filtering using multiple ids for example like where id is equal to 5, 12 and 9.

sothing like

let newArr = data.filter ...

#data

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Architect",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 12
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Construction Project Director",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 11
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "COVP",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 9
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "DVP Real Estate",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Estimator",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "Finance Director",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 15
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Local Broker",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 19
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Master Broker",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 20
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "MPR Director",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "MPR Manager",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "Project Manager",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 17
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "RE Associate",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 7
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "RE Director",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "RE Finance",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "RE Lead",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 13
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "REPM",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "Store Development Manager",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 16
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Store Planner",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "SVP Property and Store Planning",
        "isShow": true,
        "transactionRoleId": 14
    }
]
```

Comment: In this line `data.filter((sample)=>(return data.id<= 40));`, `data` is an array, `sample` arg is the object so the condition should be `sample.id <= 40`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 const idsToExlude = [5, 12, 9];
 const newData = data.filter((obj) => idsToExlude.indexOf(obj.id) === -1);
 console.log(newData);
```